# Java method calling

Tags: java

I'm new to stackoverflow, and I have question about this:

```java
public class Glavna {
    static Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    static Racunalo unosKonfiguracije(Scanner Sc){
        System.out.print("Unesite naziv proizvodzaca maticne: ");
        String maticnaPro = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite tip maticne: ");
        String maticnaTip = Sc.nextLine();
        MaticnaPloca mb = new MaticnaPloca(maticnaPro,maticnaTip);

        System.out.print("Unesite naziv proizvodzaca procesora: ");
        String proPro = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite tip procesora: ");
        String proTip = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite tip sucelja procesora: ");
        String proSuc = Sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Unesite brzinu procesora u GHz: ");
        while(!Sc.hasNextBigDecimal()){
            System.out.print("Molim unesite brzinu (u GHz sa decimalnim zarezom): ");
            Sc.next();
        }
        BigDecimal proBrz = Sc.nextBigDecimal();
        Sc.nextLine();
        Procesor pr = new Procesor(proPro,proTip,proSuc,proBrz);


        System.out.print("Unesite naziv proizvodzaca radne memorije: ");
        String memPro = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite tip radne memorije: ");
        String memTip = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite kapacitet radne memorije(u GB): ");
        while(!Sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.print("Unesite kapacitet memorije kao integer(u GB):");
            Sc.next();
        }
        int memKap = Sc.nextInt();
        Sc.nextLine();
        RadnaMemorija rm = new RadnaMemorija(memPro,memTip,memKap);

        System.out.print("Unesite naziv proizvodzaca diska: ");
        String diskPro = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite tip diska: ");
        String diskTip = Sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Unesite kapacitet diska(u TB): ");
        while(!Sc.hasNextBigDecimal()){
            System.out.print("Unesite kapacitet memorije(u GB):");
            Sc.next();
        }
        BigDecimal diskKap = Sc.nextBigDecimal();
        TvrdiDisk td = new TvrdiDisk(diskPro,diskTip,diskKap);

        //Konstruktor računala
        Racunalo r = new Racunalo(mb, pr, rm, td);

        return r;

    }
```

This is my method for computer configuration and when I try to call this method twice for two different configurations in main, I get this in console:

```
Unesite 1. konfiguraciju: 
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca maticne: 1
Unesite tip maticne: 2
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca procesora: 3
Unesite tip procesora: 4
Unesite tip sucelja procesora: 5
Unesite brzinu procesora u GHz: 6
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca radne memorije: 7
Unesite tip radne memorije: 8
Unesite kapacitet radne memorije(u GB): 9
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca diska: 10
Unesite tip diska: 11
Unesite kapacitet diska(u TB): 12
Unesite 2. konfiguraciju: 
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca maticne: Unesite tip maticne: 1 
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca procesora: 2                      
Unesite tip procesora: 3
Unesite tip sucelja procesora: 4
Unesite brzinu procesora u GHz: 5
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca radne memorije: 6
Unesite tip radne memorije: 7
Unesite kapacitet radne memorije(u GB): 8
Unesite naziv proizvodzaca diska: 9
Unesite tip diska: 10
Unesite kapacitet diska(u TB): 11
```

How can I change the code so I don't get two `system.outs` in one line as shown in second configuration input.

Comment: Yeah that was the output (at least as I understand it), I felt like editing it to distinguish the english text and the eastern european parts ;)

Comment: It is still hard for non-Croatians to read it

Comment: I hate the fact that the community immediately down votes a question from a new user while he clearly tries to do his best to formulate a proper question. At least tell the guy why he gets a down vote. Be helpful.

Comment: @Diyarbakir Well said. We gotta be constructive enough.

Comment: @Diyarbakir I did not downvote it, but I cannot blame anyone who did... It is not useful for anyone as it is right now, but downvotes can be removed after editing. In any case, downvotes should be justified in the comments.

Comment: If you want to print text on a new line (as has already been answered) either use `System.out.println(...)` or print the newline character yourself, e.g. `System.out.print("line1\nline2")`. I don't use scanners that often but I guess `Sc.nextLine()` etc. print a newline character for you in order to distinguish between input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Use println() instead of print() method

```
System.out.println("Unesite tip sucelja procesora: ");//This will print on new line everytime
```

Comment: I dont want to use System.out.println(); becouse i want to have input in same line as text, like Please enter something:   something

Comment: @DomagojPogarčić Then, add a "\n" before the start of a new line, like: `System.out.print("\nUnesite tip sucelja procesora: ")`, if I understand your requirements

Comment: @vefthym It still doesnt fix problem, when i call method first time to enter config for first PC, it works just well, but second time it starts, it connects 1st and 2nd print in 1 line and when i enter input it "skips" 1st request for input and adds it to 2nd. if you understand